# RegEx: replace two group characters global from string

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a more elegant/better way of performing the below replacement, I want to split AM and PM from all words and add a comma so is rendered as following

```
Monday, AM
Monday, PM
Wednesday, AM
Wednesday, PM
Thursday, AM
Friday, AM
Friday, PM
```

```html
<script>
let str = "MondayAM,MondayPM,TuesdayAM,WednesdayAM,ThursdayAM,ThursdayPM";
str = str.replace(/,/g,'\n').replace(/AM/g,", AM").replace(/PM/g,", PM")
console.log(str);
document.write("<pre>"+str+"</pre>")
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both data formats with a comma or a space:

```
([^\s,]+)([AP]M)\b[, \t]*
```

**Explanation**

- `([^\s,]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ non whitespace chars other than a comma
- `([AP]M)` Capture group 2, match either AM or PM
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `[, \t]*` Match optional spaces, tabs or comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JU3z6U/1)

```js
const regex = /([^\s,]+)([AP]M)\b[, \t]*/g;
const str = `MondayAM MondayPM TuesdayAM WednesdayAM ThursdayAM ThursdayPM
MondayAM,MondayPM,TuesdayAM,WednesdayAM,ThursdayAM,ThursdayPM
`;
const subst = `$1, $2\n`;
console.log(str.replace(regex, `$1, $2\n`));
```

---

Another variation matching only leading chars A-Za-z and assuming there is only a comma as a separator:

```
([A-Z][a-z]+)([AP]M)\b,?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iOMqII/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use group replacement, replace `AM` or `PM`, with the `, $1`, $1 refers to AM or PM found in the text.

```js
let str = "MondayAM MondayPM TuesdayAM WednesdayAM ThursdayAM ThursdayPM";
str = str.replace(/(AM|PM)/g, ", $1")
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in a single regex. Since you're doing the same thing with both "AM" and "PM", you can write a regex that captures either and uses `$N` expression instead of constant value, to put the captured group back to the output string.

You can also replace "," with a new line in the same expression. (I used `(,|$)` which means a comma or end of string, because there is no comma after the last entry.)

```html
<script>
let str = "MondayAM,MondayPM,TuesdayAM,WednesdayAM,ThursdayAM,ThursdayPM";
str = str.replace(/([AP]M)(,|$)/g,", $1\n")
console.log(str);
document.write("<pre>"+str+"</pre>")
</script>
```